Is there a workaround to dynamically unregister services in grpc for C++?
We have a situation where it would be beneficial to dynamically register and unregister services to a GRPC server written in C++.
I know that, for example for the Java implementation, such capabilities exist. In C++, however, it seems to be impossible (or only feasible through extremely hacky ways) to dynamically register and unregister services. Does someone know a workaround for this problem? Is the reason why this feature was never implemented known?

You may want to cross-post to https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io

https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/WqxYroLqR_A/m/_YNiC1IYAQAJ
